# Find the largest circle that can be inscribed in the union of 3 other circles (which I'm allowed to move around)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization

Thinking in 2D space and Cartesian coordinates, let there be three circles of radius 1. We would like to find centers $\bf{c}_1,\bf{c}_2,\bf{c}_3$ for these circles that allow for the largest possible circle centered at the origin and radius $r_0$ to be inscribed in their union; that is to say, any point in the interior or the boundary of this circle is also a point of the interior or boundary of at least one of the first three circles. Here's the problem written as an optimization:

\begin{array}{1}
 \mathop {\arg \max }\limits_{r_0 ,{\bf{c}}_1 ,{\bf{c}}_2 ,{\bf{c}}_3 } &r_0  \\ 
 \text{s.t.}\; &S_0  \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^3 {S_i }  \\ 
 &S_k  = \left\{ {{\bf{x}} \ |\left\| {{\bf{x}} - {\bf{c}}_k } \right\| \le r_k } \right\},{\bf{c}}_k  \in \mathbb{R} ^2 \;\forall k \in \left\{ {0,\dots ,3} \right\} \\ 
 &r_k  = 1\;\forall k \in \left\{ {1,...,3} \right\},{\bf{c}}_0  = {\bf{0}} \\ 
 \end{array}

How would you go about solving these? Either a solution, or some suggestions for which techniques / branches of mathematics would be most useful here will be very much appreciated.

Bonus problem: find the largest inscribed square (with side length $l$) instead of circle; we can let the square be aligned with the axes without loss of generality. Written as an optimization:

\begin{array}{2}
 \mathop {\arg \max }\limits_{l ,{\bf{c}}_1 ,{\bf{c}}_2 ,{\bf{c}}_3 } &l  \\ 
 \text{s.t.}\; &K  \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^3 {S_i }  \\ 
 &S_k  = \left\{ {{\bf{x}} \ |\left\| {{\bf{x}} - {\bf{c}}_k } \right\| \le r_k } \right\},{\bf{c}}_k  \in \mathbb{R} ^2 \;\forall k \in \left\{ {1,\dots ,3} \right\} \\ 
 &K = \left\{ {{\bf{x}} \ | \;  \left\| {\bf{x}} \right\|_\infty \le l/2 } \right\} \\
 &r_k  = 1 \; \forall k \in \left\{ {1,...,3} \right\} \\ 
 \end{array}

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you could rephrase by asking for the smallest $r$ such that three disks of radius $r$ "cover" the unit disk (of radius $1$). Your $r_0$ would be the reciprocal of this $r$. This, then, would be the $n=3$ case of the Disk Covering Problem (described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_covering_problem) and [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskCoveringProblem.html)), whose answer is apparently known to be $r=\sqrt{3}/2$, with the covering disks arranged symmetrically.

Comment: @Blue Yep, that's the one, thanks, now I can follow those papers.